# F# construct for grouping of constants

Tags: f#, constants

I have several pages with titles and I want to be able to define these titles as string constants in some kind of enum.  Something like this

```
pageTitles =
| HOME = "Home"
| SALES = "Sales"
| MARKETING = "Marketing"
| LOGOUT = "Logout"
```

and then use it like:

```
if title = pageTitles.SALES then
   //Goto sales
```

Comment: what you are doing seems like the right thing to do. What is your question exactly? Are you asking if there are other ways of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll have to put them in a module. Example:

```
module pageTitles =
  [<Literal>]
  let HOME = "Home"
  ...
```

Comment: It is worth adding that the `Literal` attribute makes it possible to use the constants in patter matching as patterns. (Otherwise you wouldn't need it.) I would also recommend using `PascalCase` - definitely for module name and likely also for constants.

Answer (score 4):

Combining Daniel/Tomas advice:

```
module PageTitles =
    [<Literal>]
    let HOME = "Home" 
    [<Literal>]
    let SALES = "Sales" 
...
open PageTitles
...
match title with
| HOME -> // goto home
| SALES -> // goto sales
```